# Node.js - how to process readStream for pipeline

Tags: node.js

### Problem

I'm trying to recursively walk a directory and write its paths to a file using `readdirp` module and Node's pipeline.

```js
const readdirp = require('readdirp')
const zlib = require('zlib')
const { pipeline } = require('stream')

let w_stream = fs.createWriteStream('C:/test/paths.txt')
let r_stream = readdirp('C:/Program Files')

pipeline(
  r_stream,
  zlib.createGzip(),
  w_stream,
  (error) => {
    if (error) {
      console.error('Pipeline failed', error)
    } 
    else {
      console.log('Pipeline succeeded')
    }
  }
)
```

The `r_stream` outputs objects like `{fullPath: String, stats: Object}` but the pipe expects strings. So, I get the following error:

```
The "chunk" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer or Uint8Array. Received an instance of Object
```

### Question

How do I process `r_stream` data chunks so it returns `entry.fullPath` (strings) instead of `entry` (object) into the pipeline? I tried adding the following, but I get the same error:

```
...
r_stream.on('data', (entry) => {
  w_stream.write(`${entry.fullPath}\n`)
})

pipeline(
  ...
```

How do I properly return the `entry.fullPath` string from `r_stream.on('data'...` into the pipeline?

Comment: It appears that the problem is that `r_stream` works in object mode (it streams you a series of objects), but the gzip object is expecting a stream of data to compress, not objects.  I don't know the grip library well enough to know how to fix that.

Comment: It seems like the fundamental problem here is that gzip produces a single compressed stream for a single file, but you're trying to do multiple files.  You probably need to iterate the results of `r_stream` in a `for` loop and create a new compressed file for each source file.  Your code now is attempting to feed multiple file objects from `r_stream` into a single gzip file which just isn't how it works.

Comment: Or, if all you're trying to write to the file is the filenames themselves (not the contents of the files), then you can create a transform stream that accepts the object from r_stream and outputs a line of text for each object and insert that between `r_stream` and `zlib.createGzip()` in the `pipeline()` arguments.

Comment: @jfriend00 thanks for your suggestions, yeah that's the problem, I don't know how to output `entry.fullPath<string>` instead of `entry<object>` out of `r_stream.on('data'...` into the pipeline, which expects strings

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution myself. You need to use a stream transform for this:

```js
const through2 = require('through2')
const readdirp = require('readdirp')
const zlib = require('zlib')

let w_stream = fs.createWriteStream('C:/test/paths.txt')
let r_stream = readdirp('C:/Program Files')
// note: do not use an arrow function here, otherwise 'this.push()' will be undefined
let lineTransformer = through2.obj(function(data, enc, next) {
  this.push(`${data.fullPath}\n`)
  next()
})

rstream
  .pipe(lineTransformer)
  .pipe(zlib.createGzip())
  .pipe(wstream)
```